# Understanding the One-Vs-The-Rest classifier

Tags: classification, svm

## Introduction

I am working on a multiclass classification problem by using the One-Vs-The-Rest classifier. I want to check if my understanding of the classifier is correct.

The `One-Vs-The-Rest` classifier strategy consists in fitting one binary classifier per class. We associate a set of positive examples for a given class and a set of negative examples which represent all the other classes.

For the training step, I don't want to use all the other classes as negative examples. I want to avoid the problem of unbalanced data.

In order to represent the negative examples I select a subset of examples which size is represented by: **the size of the set of positive examples plus $k$ number of negative examples.** For instasnce, if the size of the set positive examples is $10$ then the size of the set of negative examples is $k + 10=20$.

---

## Example

I'll try to use an example in here, just to see if my understanding is correct. Suppose that I have a set of $50$ observations divided into $3$ classes. I'll use the same logic as before for selecting the negative examples.

### Training k = 10

1. **Classifier 1**: has $20$ positive examples and $30$ negative examples
2. **Classifier 2**: has $16$ positive examples and $26$ negative examples
3. **Classifier 3**: has $14$ positive examples and $24$ negative examples

## Testing

My greatest misunderstanding lies in the testing step.

Suppose that I have a new instance that I want to classify into $1$ of the  previous classes. 
`Each of the three classifiers produces a probability. which is an estimation of how far of low the instance belongs to the negative or positive examples in the classifier.`

- If the instance was classified as a negative example for the $3$ classifiers therefore it doesn't belong to any of them is that right? **or else** should we always compare the probability estimates of the positive examples even if they are lower than the probabilities of the negative ones in the classifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should always compare the probabilities of positive class in one vs all. For m classes, we will have m probability estimates of positive class for one test sample. Compare them and whichever probability is maximum of m probabilities, it belongs to that particular class.

Comment: I was a little confused what if they are all negative. I asked some people. But i still don't know why always pick the positive probability if it's even lower than the negative one

Comment: @HaniGoc your negative (1 - p) probability in each case represents the probability that the sample belongs in one of all the rest of the classes; After training m one-vs-rest classifier you care about the classifier that obtained the higher probability for the positive class at hand. For the greater picture of the problem, there is no positive/negative class. Since there are m classes

Answer (score 0):

For your "**Testing**" part, you are trying to divide the feature space with infinitely long straight lines (if #features is 2). Depending on the dataset, with one-vs-rest, you might get classifiers that divide the region such that there are sub-regions that belong to no class and sub-regions that belong to multiple classes.
However, when you have a classifier that gives you a probability score (between 0 and 1) for each class for each test-sample, the region is divided in the form of a [Voronoi Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram). This makes sure that each test-sample belongs to exactly one class (except at the edges, on which you randomly select one of two).
I see I am 2 years late to answer this question, but hope this helps someone else having the same question.